# How to get API variable in function as string(python)

Tags: python

```
def get_timezone():
        timezone = requests.get("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh")
        timezone_data = timezone.text
        return (timezone_data)
```

When I use the requests.get function to get data from the api, it returns a list of variables that look like this:

{"abbreviation":"+07","client_ip":"35.247.58.151","datetime":"2021-06-23T13:13:00.379339+07:00","day_of_week":3,"day_of_year":174,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":25200,"timezone":"Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh","unixtime":1624428780,"utc_datetime":"2021-06-23T06:13:00.379339+00:00","utc_offset":"+07:00","week_number":25}

How do I make it so that the timezone_data variable only stores the variable "datetime" within the list?

Comment: This is json string you can convert into a dictionary with the help of `json.loads`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_timezone():
    timezone = requests.get("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh")
    timezone_data = timezone.json()
    return timezone_data['datetime']
```

You can also convert this to datetime python object:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime


def get_datetime():
    timezone = requests.get("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh")
    timezone_data = timezone.json()
    return datetime.fromisoformat(timezone_data['datetime'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
timezone = requests.get("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh").json()['timezone'] 
print(timezone)
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary from the json response and than use `datetime` as a key

```
def get_timezone():
    response = requests.get("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh")
    content = json.loads(response.content)
    return content['datetime'] # 2021-06-23T13:30:50.753819+07:00
```

Answer (score 0):

The API will return the data with the str type. First, you have to load that with the help of JSON. It will convert it into the dict type. Now you can fetch the data from the dict.

```
import requests
import json

def get_timezone():
    timezone = requests.get("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh")
    data = json.loads(timezone.text)
    timezone_data = data['datetime']
    return (timezone_data)

print(get_timezone())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is 2 Methods:

Method 1

- Using requests `.json()` Method

**Code :**

```
def get_timezone():
        timezone = requests.get("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh")
        timezone_data = timezone.json()
        return timezone_data['datetime']
```

Method 2:
Using `json.loads()`

**Code :**

```
import json
import requests

def get_timezone():
        timezone = requests.get("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh")
        timezone_data = json.loads(timezone.text)
        return timezone_data['datetime']
```

In Both Case, You will get data like a dictionary in Python.